# Difference between cURL and web browser?

Tags: php, curl, get

I am trying to retrieve a web page from the following url:

http://www.medicare.gov/find-a-doctor/provider-results.aspx?searchtype=OHP&specgrpids=922&loc=43615&pref=No&gender=Unknown&dist=25&lat=41.65603&lng=-83.66676

It works when I paste it into a browser, but when I run it through cURL, I receive a page with the following error: **"One or more query string parameters of requested url are invalid or has unexpected value, please correct and retry."**

It doesn't seem to make a difference if I provide a different userAgent or referrer. There is a redirect, so I use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init($page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

Any thoughts on why a request like this will work in the browser and not with cURL?

Comment: i get same error, what you get with cURL

Comment: Instead of following location, trap the redirect and see where you're being sent. Is that the same between the curl and browser versions?

Comment: That link comes up with the error "One or more query string parameters of requested url are invalid or has unexpected value, please correct and retry." on my browser, might need to add a cookie jar to curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with cookies. This particular site needed an ASP.NET_SessionId cookie set in order to respond. I added the following to my cURL request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'ASP.NET_SessionId=ho1pqwa0nb3ys3441alenm45; path=/; domain=www.medicare.gov');
```

I don't know if any session id will work, but it tried a couple random ones and they all worked.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is sending cookies that cURL is not. Check the cookies you are sending to the site using browser tools or Fidler - you'll need to pass the same.

Comment: Curl offers many features such as proxy support, user authentication, FTP upload, HTTP post, SSL connections, **cookies**, file transfer resume, Metalink, as well as various other features. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL#Examples_of_cURL_use_from_command_line